# Do AWS CloudWatch Logs Events have a Synchronized Clock?

Tags: amazon-web-services, logging, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

What assumptions can I make about clock synchronization between events in **different** log streams?
That is, can I assume that if the timestamp of event 1 is earlier than the timestamp of event 2, then indeed event 1 happened before event 2?